# Coordinate of a division point.

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Given that the line which connects the points $(-6,2)$ and $(-7,5)$ is externally divided by a point in ratio of $2:3$, find out the coordinate of the division point.

Comment: Why do you need two sets of coordinates? The single point that provides that external division will have coordinates (x, y) such that the distance from (x, y) to (-6, 2) is 2/3 the distance from (x, y) to (-7, 5) and (x, y) lies on the line connecting the two while not being between them.

Comment: My question is that how can I know that (-6,2)(or other point) is nearer to the divisior point.

Comment: Since the ratio is 2:3 and not 3:2, the length between (x, y) and (-6, 2) must be the one that is 2 parts, and the length between (x, y) and (-7, 5) is the one that's 3 parts. So clearly (-6, 2) is closer.

Comment: That means the order/sequence of the ratio should follow the order of the points in a question?

Comment: Yes. A 2:3 ratio is not the same as a 3:2 ratio.